# MySQL Date related query runs in phpMyAdmin but not in Script

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

`SELECT id FROM videos WHERE dateAdded BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 day) AND CURDATE()`

The query above does as expected in phpMyAdmin and returns several results within the date range, but when I run the query within the php script the result is always empty (false).

This query gives results
`SELECT id FROM videos WHERE 1`

The project is rather old running php 5.3 using PDO to run the mysql statements. PDO::errorInfo() indicates that the query went through without errors. It is as if the WHERE part was not interpreted or it was in a different way.

dateAdded is a dateTime parameter that stores the current timestamp of the creation of that particular row.

I already tried to replace the 2 dates with preformatted dates e.g. '2021-06-11 00:00:00' but it did not change anything.

Answer (score -1):

I reworked the script to use mysqli instead of PDO. Now it works properly. It seems like PDO and mysqli treat date related queries different somehow.

Comment: Hate to say the same, but apparently here you had some similar mistake on your part. Of course there is no difference at all between mysqli and pdo. I bet your phpmyadmin and mysqli simply connected  to different databases.

Comment: @YourCommonSense no. There is only one db to connect to and other queries went through. Hoewever, I could solve it this way.